# Make button call same button's method

Tags: android

So I have two buttons, Left and Right. Both have same

```
setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            }
```

methods inside it but I want my code reduced, so is there a possibility I can just make the Left Button call the onClick method of Right Button? instead of having duplicate methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the onclick as a private instance variable of your class:

```
public class Blah {

  private OnClickListener myListener = new OnClickListener() { .. };

  public onCreate(...) { 
    ...
    button1.setOnClickListener(myListener);
    button2.setOnClickListener(myListener);
  }
}
```